# How to use object key from string value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have sample object, need to reassign the value dynamically.

here is sample object, i have stored the object in dynamodb with inarray data type. i have formed the object by using loop. i couldn't use the payload.offer value. kindly suggest the better solution.

```
{
  organization_id: 4002400004,
  organization_name: 'Velocity Global Integration Sandbox',
  'payload.offer': 'payload offer',
}
```

Required output format

```
    {
      organization_id: 4002400004,
      organization_name: 'Velocity Global Integration Sandbox',
      'payload': {
        offer: 'payload offer'
    },
}
```

Comment: for some reason your code addressed the property 'payload.offer' instead of creating a nested object in the `payload` property. Maybe you should share the code that created that output to be corrected ... or share what the input should be. Because the problem lies in how you built that output and there's no solution to give here in those terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want a way to convert from dot-notation to deeply-nested objects. You can try the following then:

```js
function dotToNested(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((newObj, [key, value]) => {
    const path = key.split(".");

    // This part makes it recursive, you can just use value if you don't want that
    const newValue = typeof value === "object" && !!value
      ? dotToNested(value)
      : value;
    
    if (path.length > 1) {
      // Last key will be used for assignment
      const newKey = path.pop();

      // Get the object to assign to, and create the intermediate objects along the way
      const objRef = path.reduce((ref, key) => {
        // create the intermediate object
        ref[key] = {};

        // move further down in the deeply nested structure
        return ref[key];
      }, newObj);
      
      objRef[newKey] = newValue;
    } else {
      // Just a "regular" key, assign directly to it, no need for the path
      newObj[key] = newValue;
    }

    return newObj;
  }, {});
}

const dotNotation = {
  organization_id: 4002400004,
  organization_name: 'Velocity Global Integration Sandbox',
  'payload.offer': 'payload offer',
};

const deeplyNested = dotToNested(dotNotation);

console.log({ dotNotation, deeplyNested });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the top level method **Object.keys()** from the standard Object prototype,
and **split('.')** the target key, and try to delete the old key and add the new key.

Well, this is my code suggestion

```
const input = {
    organization_id: 4002400004,
    organization_name:
        'Velocity Global Integration Sandbox',
    'payload.offer': 'payload offer',
};


function modify(input, requireKey) {
    const newObject = {};
    Object.keys(input).forEach((key) => {
        if (key === requireKey) {
            let [newKey, newDownLevelKey] = key.split('.');

            delete Object.assign(newObject, input, {
                [newKey]: input[key],
            })[key];

            newObject[newKey] = {
                [newDownLevelKey]: newObject[newKey],
            };
        }
    });
    return newObject;
}

console.log(modify(input, 'payload.offer'));
```

**Resources :**

Object.assign() : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Object.keys() : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys